# How to clear the session using a button and javascript

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Session is client side staff, but is it possible through clear it using javascript code?
I would like too have the idea like this and ,can it convert  to jquery format? Thank you.

js

```
    $(function(){
  $("#closeTab").click(function() {
    window.parent.$('#tt').tabs('close','Create List');
        $.post("clear.php",function(data){
      });
  });
});
```

php

```
    <?
if (isset($_SESSION['lname']))
unset($_SESSION['lname']);
if (isset($_POST['creminder']))
unset($_SESSION['creminder']);
?>
```

Is this one ok ?

Comment: Clear or end the session? There's a big difference...

Comment: I think should be unset($_SESSION['cart']); or $_SESSION['cart']=''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make an ajax call to the server and let your server page kills/ends the session

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="aKill" > Kill Session</a>
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){

  $("#aKill").click(function(){
        $.post("serverpage.php",function(data){
        // if you want you can show some message to user here
     });
});
```

and in your serverpage.php, Execute the PHP script to terminate the session.

Comment: Can i do it without alert? would you mind slightly modify it? thank you

Comment: @user782104 : Just take it out the alert then . I updated the answer now

Comment: no ,of course, would you help me , how to go to a specific page when pressing a button?

Comment: @user782104 : Which page ? elaborate that pls. May be as a new question

Comment: I elaborate it clearly, take a look if you are free. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781152/session-lost-if-use-location-href

Comment: Sorry the session still there

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate file to clear the session only. `clearsession.php`

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

Now, make a simple request

```
$("#aKill").click(function(){
    $.get("clearsession.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below covers the basics more or less.

**The Function:**

```
function destroySession(){
  var theForm = $("#yourForm");
  //we don't need any ajax frame.
  theForm.each(function(){ this.reset() });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'destroysession.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'sure=1', //send a value to make sure we want to destroy it.
    success: function(data);
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

**The PHP** *(destroysession.php)*:

```
<?php
  //whatever logic is necessary


  if(!empty($_POST['sure'])){ 
     $sure = $_POST['sure'];
     if($sure == 1){
       //logic to destroy session
       echo 'Session Destroyed!';
     }else if($sure != 1){
       //logic to perform if we're being injected.
       echo 'That value is incorrect. What are you doing over there?';
     }
  }else{
     //logic to perform if we're being injected.
     echo 'That value is incorrect. What are you doing over there?';
  }
?>
```

**The HTML:**

```
<input type='button' value='reset' onclick='destroySession()'>
```